# Login Prompt when accessing new mobile service from browser

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I am just learning Mobile Services. I've created a simple one which works fine locally. I published the mobile service to my Azure account. I then tried to access a method on it from the browser and I get a log in dialog. I figured out that I need to provide the application key generated by Azure as the password. Once I do this, it executes correctly. However, is there a way I can execute a method without providing a key? In other words, what if I wanted to expose one or more methods to everyone, without any authentication. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. There are **four authentication levels** in Windows Azure Mobile Services.

- scripts and admins
- authenticated users
- users with application key
- everyone

By default, the authentication level is set to "users with application key".
Depending on the backend you use, you either have to specify the auth level in the Management Portal in the data-tab (Javascript) or as a method attribute in your Controller-class (.NET) to "**everyone**".